# IE Button issue

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer, button

There is an issue with the button "learn more" in IE only that causes it to run down the page and distort the layout. 
Page URL: http://www.mvholisticretreat.com/
CSS: http://www.mvholisticretreat.com/wp-content/themes/nebula/style.css
any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you !

Comment: Check the console for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue 1: clean up your code, you have a useless endif in

issue 2: you have some styles before your doctype. this is why IE loads by default in quirks mode. fix your doctype declaration and it's almost fixed.
To preview issue, in IE9 press F12, and from the quirks mode dropdown chose IE 9 Standards, you'll see how the site gets fixed

Comment: thank you!! I realize this was very amateur and appreciate the help!